# sql sum and count functions with inner join

Tags: sql, count, sum

```
select * 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.tid
```

returns 102 rows

```
select sum(t1.val), count(t1.val) 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.tid
```

returns 29000  103

That means the second query doesnt work correctly. What the problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af488/1)?

Comment: We need SqlFiddle // table scripts.

Comment: This seems to be impossible. You cant get more values using the same join. You must have a typo OR mixed the results OR you're not pasting the actual queries.

Comment: I can't reproduce in sql fiddle. See this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a5f0/3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your 103 values has null in val column.

```
select sum(t1.val), count(*) 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.tid
```

This should return 103 for count. At least in MS SQL Server. But I think it's part of SQL ANSI, so should work for all SQL ANSI compliant database engines

Comment: But if 1 of the 103 is null then the second query should return 102, right?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk You were a bit more harsh than me :P

Comment: Oh. I looked though those results and they don't make any sense.. You can get only less results in count(t1.val), not more.. Dude, maybe someone inserted more values between those request ))

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk My description is correct, the question is a bit strange

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't show real query and answer, but it's true. And I've already checked and rechecked all variants. The only one reason may be that we use special sql parser before send query to execute

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified a DBMS, I'm answering based on just `SQL`, as you tagged it. Anyway, this should apply to any DBMS.

You have 2 different queries that have the same join. The join will generate the same amount of results in both cases. It is clear from the first one that there are 102 results after the join.

If you then want to count those rows there is not way that you get more rows than there really are. What can happen is that you get less because the `count(field)` aggregation function will count only non-null values for `field`.

However, you stated that you got more and that is absolutely not possible.